# Android: Cannot load library

Tags: android-ndk

I am  facing a situation of which I have no idea. I am tried to test one method that I have implemented in C++ and I used swig to generate the wrapper. After compilation, when I tried to run the application, I got an error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

It further states that

```
cannot load library:reloc_library[1311]:33
cannot locate '_Z13recognizeFacePKcS0_'
...
```

and suddenly throw exception.

I tried using adb shell to debug and found library in the right location *(data/data/com/mesh/faceAuth/lib/libfaceAuth.so)* but it  gives the same error. I also read from [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Android) site, that it has to do with wrong STL implementation which I don't have any clue of. I will highly appreciate your candid suggestion.

Regards,
Mohammed.

Answer (score 2):

Best guess with what information you have provided, The library you are trying to load needs some dependencies to be loaded before it.

For example:

```
System.loadLibrary("bullet");
System.loadLibrary("irrlicht");
System.loadLibrary("gamescript");
```

`gamescript` library needs other 2 library to be loaded before it. Otherwise, it gives me the same error you have mentioned. I can dig further on this issue if you can post some part of your `.mk` file for building the library here.

Comment: LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
include ../includeOpenCV.mk
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(OPENCV_MK_PATH))","")
 #try to load OpenCV.mk from default install location
 include $(TOOLCHAIN_PREBUILT_ROOT)/user/share/OpenCV/OpenCV.mk
else
 include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)
endif


LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl
   
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += jni/faceAuth.h

LOCAL_MODULE    := faceRec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := faceAuth.cpp gen/faceAuth_wrap.cpp 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: Lastest Error,No implementation found for native Lcom/android/faceAuth/core/faceAuthJNI;.init (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with STL.

You probably reference a global function `::recognizeFace(char const*, char const*)` in your code. Maybe, you have another function defined, for example `recognizeFace(char*, char*)`.